# Why is there a tag called [tex-history]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Islam SE [does not have [islamic-history]](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/608/156).

Chsitiantity SE is a bit more precise with [[history], [church-history], and [early-church]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tags/history/info) tags.

---

Anyway, surely on this site, a TeX context can be assumed, and [history] would be perfectly understandable as a tag in its own right, without the *tex-* prefix.

Comment: [tag:history] might be a field identifier such as [tag:linguistics], [tag:graphs] etc. though I can't think of why it would needed. Nevertheless better safe than sorry later.

Comment: I have historians using LaTeX, so it's conceivable that they might want to tag a question that way.